# App get frozen while plotting points in real time in MSchart control

Tags: winforms, serial-port, real-time, mschart

I am using MSchart control to plot point that arrive by using serialPort (class) with `DataReceived event`, I use this method to thread safe plot points that arrive:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>{ 
 Serie.Points.AddXY(daux1.CoordenadaX, daux1.CoordenadaY);
}));
```

I use RadDock control with:

1. tooltabStrip
2. DocuemtnTabStrip
3. toolTabStrip (this get frozen) docked in this order

If I get floating docked window 3, gets responsive, if dock it again get frozen

I dont know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: That should work fine, I have done this before on the `DataRecieved` event.  I type mine a little different than yours but it should work.  

`this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
 Series.Points.AddXY(daux1.CoordenadaX, daux1.CoordenadaY);
});`

Comment: Should also note that `this` needs to be your gui form.  So if the chart is on Form1, you can use `Form1.Invoke` because maybe 'this' isnt your main gui.